# can't open texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I've installed textstudio in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Since yesterday it does not work anymore. I try to open a tex file with it, but it popped out for less than a second and closed itself automatically. I tried to install it again, but it did not succeed and followings are the error messages. Is there anyone had the same issue before? Thanks!

---

```
(Reading database ... 405177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texstudio_2.10.8+debian-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.10.8+debian-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/texstudio', which is also in package texstudio-qt4 2.11.0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../texstudio-doc_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio-doc (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio-doc_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/template_Moderncv.png', which is also in package texstudio-qt4 2.11.0
Preparing to unpack .../texstudio-l10n_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio-l10n (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio-l10n_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/texstudio_pt_BR.qm', which is also in package texstudio-qt4 2.11.0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.10.8+debian-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio-doc_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio-l10n_2.10.8+debian-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you have installed a different version of texstudio from a different source, i.e. not from one of the regular repositories.  Go to the command line, type `sudo aptitude search texstudio` and you should see this:

> i   texstudio                       - LaTeX Editor
>   p   texstudio:i386                  - LaTeX Editor
>   p   texstudio-dbg                   - LaTeX Editor (debug)
>   p   texstudio-dbg:i386              - LaTeX Editor (debug)
>   i A texstudio-doc                   - LaTeX Editor (doc)
>   i A texstudio-l10n                  - LaTeX Editor (localization)

Remove any additional packages listed in the output of your command by typing `sudo apt-get remove <package-name>` replacing  with whatever the name of the extra package is.  Then type `sudo apt-get install texstudio` to install the correct version.  Good luck.

Comment: maybe worth noting that one needs to remove both texstudio as well as texstudio-doc